# Как по символьному значению даты и времени отрисовывать график только по дате?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Есть следующий Датасет:

```
Index   Data
0   2017-05-08 21:46:36+00:00
1   2017-05-09 21:46:34+00:00
2   2017-05-10 21:46:34+00:00
3   2017-05-11 21:46:17+00:00
4   2017-05-12 21:46:17+00:00
```

Необходимо в колонке `Data` оставить только дату формата `%Y-%m-%d`

То есть, на выходе необходимо получить:

```
Index   Data
0   2017-05-08
1   2017-05-09
2   2017-05-10
3   2017-05-11
4   2017-05-12
```

Comment: По-моему в `Pandas` нет отдельного типа чисто для даты. Можно либо обнулить время, либо превратить в строку нужного формата. Вам с какой целью это нужно?

Comment: Чтобы в дальнейшем график отрисовывать по числам

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по дополнительной информации из комментариев, вы пытаетесь нарисовать график, используя в качестве значений по оси `X` **строки**, в которых хранится дата и время. Pandas не понимает на сколько отличается одна строковая дата от другой и поэтому на графике вы получите совсем не то, что ожидаете.

Приведите столбец `Data` к типу данных `datetime64` и попробуйте начертить график средствами Pandas - скорее всего вы получите приемлемый результат, даже не обрезая компоненту времени.

```
df["Data"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Data"])
df.set_index("Date")["<column_name_to_plot>"].plot()
```

---

Пример:

```
In [134]: df = pd.DataFrame({"dt": ["2000-01-01", "2000-01-02", "2021-10-10"], "val": [1,2,3]})

In [135]: df.set_index("dt").plot()
Out[135]: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='dt'>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
а теперь нарисуем тот же самый график, предварительно преобразовав столбец `"dt"` к типу данных `datetime64`:

```
In [136]: df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"])

In [137]: df.set_index("dt").plot()
Out[137]: <AxesSubplot:xlabel='dt'>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну почему же, мне кажется если формат будет именно год-месяц-день, то строки нормально отсортируются просто в лексикогдафическом порядке. Чем и хорош именно такой формат даты-времени от старших сущностей к младшим )

Comment: @CrazyElf, это сработает только для "barplot". Для обычного графика получится ерунда, т.к. Pandas не сможет правильно посчитать разницу во времени между ближайшими датами. Я добавил пример в ответ

Comment: А, ну если в датах есть пропуски, тогда да. Я думал там всё подряд есть и вопрос только в правильной сортировке.

Answer (score 1):

Отдельно даты как типа в `Pandas` вроде бы нет, можно превратить дату-время в строку нужного формата:

```
df['Data'] = df['Data'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
```

Ну либо так (как напомнил strawdog):

```
df['Data'] = df["Data"].dt.date
```

А если у вас там строки, а не даты, то попробуйте так:

```
df['Data'] = df["Data"].str.slice(0, 10)
```

Comment: df["Data"].dt.date

Comment: @strawdog Но тогда там всё же `datetime` останется, просто с нулевым временем? Так тоже можно, конечно

Comment: нет, будет object

Comment: @CrazyElf, код не работает, выдает ошибку : "Can only use .dt accessor with datetimelike values"

Comment: @CR7 Добавил вариант